# Pass a directory with argparse (no type checking needed)

Tags: python, argparse

I've written a file crawler and I'm trying to expand it. I want to use argparse to handle settings for the script including passing the starting directory in at the command line.

Example: `/var/some/directory/`

I have gotten several other arguments to work but I'm unable to pass this directory in correctly. I don't care if it's preceded by a flag or not, (e.g `-d /path/to/start/`) but I need to make sure that at the very least, this is argument is used as it will be the only mandatory option for the script to run.

Code Sample:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='py pub crawler...')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', help='verbose output from crawler', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dump', help='dumps and replaces existing dictionaries', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-f', '--fake', help='crawl only, nothing stored to DB', action="store_true")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.verbose:
    verbose = True
if args.dump:
    dump = True
if args.fake:
    fake = True
```

Comment: can you show your code?  This should be a pretty easy thing to do ... Maybe seeing your code will help us to understand what you're having a hard time with.

Comment: I don't have anything for passing the directory right now. I've tried various options but have gotten nowhere worth keeping.

Comment: If you do want type checking, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11415570/247696

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add:

```
parser.add_argument('directory',help='directory to use',action='store')
```

before your `args = parser.parse_args()` line.  A simple test from the commandline shows that it does the right thing (printing `args` at the end of the script):

```
$ python test.py /foo/bar/baz
Namespace(directory='/foo/bar/baz', dump=False, fake=False, verbose=False)
$ python test.py
usage: test.py [-h] [-v] [-d] [-f] directory
test.py: error: too few arguments
```

Comment: can I just use `'directory'` as the variable holding my path from that point on?

Comment: @frankV -- It'll be `args.directory`, but you can easily just do `directory = args.directory` if you want to.