# Parse path as argument in python script and how to type the path in the cmd window

Tags: python, argparse, filepath

This part of the code always returns `None`

```py
import argparse
from pathlib import Path


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', "--file_path", type=Path)

p = parser.parse_args()
print(p.file_path)
```

I need to understand why this is happening.
How could I solve it and how to correctly type a path in the *cmd* window?

Comment: Please see [mcve]. What does "this" in "I need to understand why this is happening" mean?

Comment: @hc_dev. I explicitly downvoted the answers, exactly for "supposing" when there is not a clear question being asked.

Comment: Sorry guys It was my first time posting I will try to make it more clear next time. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Works as expected

I saved your given script as `SO_argparse_Path.py` and run it with python3 and the argument `-f Downloads/`. See how it prints `Downloads` as expected folder:

```sh
$ python3 SO_argparse_Path.py -f Downloads/
```

which should print:

> Downloads

On Windows you could run the script similarly in CMD.exe, e.g. with `C:\`:

```
python SO_argparse_Path.py -f C:\
```

which should print:

> C:\

Paths with spaces inside should be wrapped inside doouble-quotes, see [Handle spaces in argparse input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157376/handle-spaces-in-argparse-input)

### About argument types

From the docs of *argparse* on parameter [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type):

> The argument to `type` can be **any callable that accepts a single string**. If the function raises ArgumentTypeError, TypeError, or ValueError, the exception is caught and a nicely formatted error message is displayed. No other exception types are handled.

(emphasis mine), also see the examples for built-in types there like:
`parser.add_argument('datapath', type=pathlib.Path)`

For a custom argument-handler see:
[path to a directory as argparse argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834378/path-to-a-directory-as-argparse-argument)