# Reading named command arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

Can I use `argparse` to read named command line arguments that do not need to be in a specific order? I browsed through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) but most of it focused on displaying content based on the arguments provided (such as `--h`).

Right now, my script reads ordered, unnamed arguments:

> myscript.py foo-val bar-val

using `sys.argv`:

```
foo = sys.argv[1]
bar = sys.argv[2]
```

But I would like to change the input so that it is order agnostic by naming arguments:

> myscript.py --bar=bar-val --foo=foo-val

Comment: cannot find a good duplicate, but check here for some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415570/directory-path-types-with-argparse

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use the [Optional Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.10/howto/argparse.html#introducing-optional-arguments) like so.

With this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse, sys

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--bar", help="Do the bar option")
parser.add_argument("--foo", help="Foo the program")

args=parser.parse_args()

print(f"Args: {args}\nCommand Line: {sys.argv}\nfoo: {args.foo}")
print(f"Dict format: {vars(args)}")
```

Make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x prog.py
```

Then if you call it with:

```
$ ./prog.py --bar=bar-val --foo foo-val
```

It prints:

```
Args: Namespace(bar='bar-val', foo='foo-val')
Command Line: ['./prog.py', '--bar=bar-val', '--foo', 'foo-val']
foo: foo-val
Dict format: {'bar': 'bar-val', 'foo': 'foo-val'}
```

Or, if the user wants help argparse builds that too:

```
 $ ./prog.py -h
usage: prog.py [-h] [--bar BAR] [--foo FOO]

options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --bar BAR   Do the bar option
  --foo FOO   Foo the program
```

---

2022-08-30: Updated to Python3 this answer...

Comment: how do I read the value of `foo` after the args have been loaded ?

Comment: is there like `args.get('foo')` ?

Comment: Use `args.bar` to read `--bar` It will return `None` if not included in the command. You can also use a default instead.

Comment: Using python 3.5.1, and when not included it doesn't return `None`; it gives an error. 
So as an alternative, `d = vars(args)` gives a dictionary (maps named arguments to values)

Comment: @MikhailV: Just to show what was on the command line prior to processing with the `print sys` at the end.

Comment: @dawg ah,ok. In python 3 it does not work. It works with `print (sys.argv)`.

Answer (score 42):

The answer is **yes**. A quick look at [the argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse) would have answered as well.

Here is a very simple example, argparse is able to handle far more specific needs.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', '-f', help="a random options", type= str)
parser.add_argument('--bar', '-b', help="a more random option", type= int, default= 0)

print(parser.format_help())
# usage: test_args_4.py [-h] [--foo FOO] [--bar BAR]
# 
# optional arguments:
#   -h, --help         show this help message and exit
#   --foo FOO, -f FOO  a random options
#   --bar BAR, -b BAR  a more random option

args = parser.parse_args("--foo pouet".split())
print(args)  # Namespace(bar=0, foo='pouet')
print(args.foo) # pouet
print(args.bar) # 0
```

Off course, in a real script, you won't hard-code the command-line options and will call `parser.parse_args()` (without argument) instead. It will make argparse take the `sys.args` list as command-line arguments.

You will be able to call this script this way:

```
test_args_4.py -h  # prints the help message
test_args_4.py -f pouet  # foo="pouet", bar=0 (default value)
test_args_4.py -b 42  # foo=None, bar=42
test_args_4.py -b 77 -f knock  # foo="knock", bar=77
```

You will discover a lot of other features by reading the doc ;)

Comment: but in your script, you don't know that 'pouet' is passed as the arg value

Comment: in line `args = parser.parse_args("--foo pouet".split())`, why do you hard code what argument value the script should read rather than reading whatever was supplied by the command ?

Comment: @amphibient This is an example to show you how to access the arguments values then. in a real script, you will just call `parser.parse_args()` with no argument and it will take the `sys.args` list

Answer (score 3):

I think it might help you with a simple one

```
#! /usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                    
import sys                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                   
keys = ["--paramkey=","-p="]                                                                                                           
for i in range(1,len(sys.argv)):                                                                                                       
    for key in keys:                                                                                                                   
        if sys.argv[i].find(key) == 0:                                                                                                 
            print(f"The Given value is: {sys.argv[i][len(key):]}")                                                                     
            break
```

Run:

```
$ ./example.py --paramkey=paramvalue -p=pvalue
```

Output:

```
The Given value is: paramvalue
The Given value is: pvalue
```