# How to argparse a range specified with 1-3 and return a list

Tags: python, parsing, command-line, range, argparse

hi basically i want to add a --cid argument to my argument, when given in the command line --cid 1-3 7 22 ,  the parsed args are a list [1,2,3,7,22].

current attempt:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentTypeError
import re

def parseNumList(string):
    print 'in string:',string
    if '-' in string:
        m = re.match(r'(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$', string)
        # ^ (or use .split('-'). anyway you like.)
        if not m:
            raise ArgumentTypeError("'" + string + "' is not a range of number. Expected forms like '0-5' or '2'.")
        start = m.group(1)
        end = m.group(2) or start
        return list(range(int(start,10), int(end,10)+1))
    else:
        return string

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--cid', type=parseNumList,nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

but the result is this, i don't want nested list, how do i do it ? (i know i can again parse args.cid manually and reassign it, but can i finish all this in argparse itself ? using custom actions or custom type ? )

```
> python testArgs.py --cid 1-3 7 22
in string: 1-3
in string: 7
in string: 22
Namespace(cid=[[1, 2, 3], '7', '22'])
```

edit:
got it working with custom actions, but have a feeling it's not the best way of doing this. any suggestions ?

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentTypeError,Action
import re

class CustomRangeAction(Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print 'running action for ' + repr(values)

        flatten = []

        for v in values:
            try:
                m = re.match(r'(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$', v)  
                if m:
                    start = m.group(1)
                    end = m.group(2) or start
                    flatten.extend(list(range(int(start,10), int(end,10)+1)))
                else:
                    flatten.append(int(v))
            except:
                continue

        flatten = sorted(list(set(flatten)))
        flatten.reverse()

        setattr(namespace, self.dest, flatten)


parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--cid', action=CustomRangeAction,nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Comment: `except:` **never** use bare `except`. In your case you probably want to check just for `ValueError` and `TypeError` so use: `except (ValueError, TypeError): continue` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it is to use `action=` not `type=` in `add_argument` to define special behavior. You should use type when each argument is of a special type (for example, each argument is a hex string representing a number). In this case some of your arguments need to be inflated into more than one.

In order to define an action, you need to define a new class (inherting from `argparse.Action`) and implementing the `__call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None)` method:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentTypeError, Action
import re

class InflateRange(Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print('%r %r %r' % (namespace, values, option_string))
        lst = []
        for string in values:
            print 'in string:',string
            if '-' in string:
                m = re.match(r'(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$', string)
                # ^ (or use .split('-'). anyway you like.)
                if not m:
                    raise ArgumentTypeError("'" + string + "' is not a range of number. Expected forms like '0-5' or '2'.")
                start = m.group(1)
                end = m.group(2) or start
                lst.extend(list(range(int(start,10), int(end,10)+1)))
            else:
                 lst.append(int(string))
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, lst)

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--cid', action=InflateRange, nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

This way you'll get:

```
> python test.py --cid 1-3 7 22
Namespace(cid=None) ['1-3', '7', '22'] '--cid'
in string: 1-3
in string: 7
in string: 22
Namespace(cid=[1, 2, 3, 7, 22])
```

For more information, check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action)

Comment: Just what I was looking for! **As a side note**: if you raise `ArgumentTypeError(errMsg)` in case of malformed parameter, it will print the stack trace and abort. If you use `parser.error(errMsg)` or `ArgumentParser.error(parser, errMsg)` instead, it will print the error message and usage and exit, hiding the exception details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for your `parseNumList` method. I am assuming `input_string` is the input to the method.

```
>>> input_string = '1-3 7 22'
>>> input_list = input_string.split()
>>> alist = []
>>> for item in input_list:
...     if '-' in item:
...             a, b = item.split('-')
...             alist.extend(range(int(a), int(b) + 1))
...     else:
...             alist.append(int(item))
...
>>> alist
[1, 2, 3, 7, 22]
```

You could add errors and bounds checking wherever you feel appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ["The correct way to do it..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23028192/65889) is on the right track, but I had to change the code of the `InflateRange` class to make it actually work.

Also, in order to keep the errors contained inside `argparse`, the raised exceptions need to be of type `ArgumentError` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9881972/65889) answer).

The code for the custom action then looks like this:

```
class InflateRange(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        lst = []

        limits = values.split('-')
        if len(limits) > 2:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, "%r is not a range of numbers." % part )
        start = limits[0]
        if start == '': start = '1'
        end = limits[-1]
        try:
            lst.extend(list(range(int(start), int(end)+1)))
        except ValueError:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, "%r is not a range of numbers." % part )

        setattr(namespace, self.dest, lst)
```